# 100k bit column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, index

What is the best way to be store, query & index a column containing around 100k bits?

I am attempting to do it creating a table like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.search_bf
(
    id serial,
    bf integer ARRAY[3125]
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);
```

So column `bf` would have 3125 32bit integers which would give me the neccessary bits. I'm now trying to find a way of indexing and querying this.

I would like to use intarray but this doesn't work for bits.

I could use intarray if I just created a column `integer ARRAY[100000]` but this would be really inefficent in terms of storage.

Comment: How do you want to query the table?

Comment: I'll be testing a single bit of the data making sure that it equals 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I'm moving ahead with is to have an `smallint[]` which esentially gives me a total of 65k unique values / bits. I will then store the index of the bits that are 'on'. This won't be very efficent in terms of storage if densely populated. I could use int4 for higher indexes but this would consume even more space.

I can query it for off bits using `@>` operator.

I should be able to index this with a `GIN` index.